# Cannot create Multi-Device Hybrid App project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, visual-studio-cordova

I've installed the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio 2013 CTP 2.0, however I can not create a project, as I get the following message:

```
This project cannot be created because Node.js could not be found.
```

I already had Node.js installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe` before I installed this extension.

Where can I set the path so that this extensions finds Node.js? I cannot see anything under Tools -> Options -> Multi-Device Hybrid Apps.

EDIT:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` is in my System Path variable.
- I'm running Visual Studio 2013 as Administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. The solution to this problem was to un-install Nodejs, then re-run the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps extension installation.

Answer (score 0):

Wayne,

Could you check if your node install folder is in your system Path? If not, please add `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\` to the path and try creating your project again.

We add the node folder to your path when you install node through our installer. Since you already had node installed, did you uncheck the "Joyent Node.js" option while installing our tools? This might have led to the folder not being added to the path.

Let us know if that unblocks you.

**EDIT**

A couple more things

1. In the registry **HKCU\Software\Node.js**, there should be a registry value "InstallPath". Could you check if that value exists and points to an existing folder on disk and that the folder contains Node.exe?
2. Does the nodejs folder under program files contain the node.exe file?

Thanks!
-Avani

Comment: Thanks for your response. Node is (and was already) in my path. I don't remember unchecking Nodejs when installing.

Comment: The InstallPath registry exists and is correct, and the nodejs folder definitely contains the node.exe file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I upvoted you (somebody else downvoted?). The solution was to de-install Nodejs and run a repair on the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps extension.